# Efficiently create structured binary decision diagram

Tags: data-structures, sat, boolean-algebra, binary-decision-diagram, pyeda

I'm trying to create a BDD with a particular structure. I have a 1D sequence of boolean variables x_i, e.g. x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5. My condition is satisfied if there are no isolated ones or zeros (except possibly at the edges).

I have implemented this using [pyeda](https://pyeda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/2llm.html) as follows. The condition is equivalent to examining consecutive triples ([x_1, x_2, x_3]; [x_2, x_3, x_4]; ...) and checking that their truth values are one of [[1,1,1], [0,0,0], [1,1,0], [0,1,1], [1,0,0], [0,0,1]].

```py
from functools import reduce
from pyeda.inter import bddvars

def possible_3_grams(farr):
    farr = list(farr)
    poss = [[1,1,1], [0,0,0], [1,1,0], [0,1,1], [1,0,0], [0,0,1]]
    truths = [[farr[i] if p[i] else ~farr[i] for i in range(3)] for p in poss]
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, [reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, t) for t in truths])

X = bddvars('x', k)
Xc = [X[i-1:i+2] for i in range(1,k-1)]
cont_constraints = [possible_3_grams(c) for c in Xc]
cont_constr = reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, cont_constraints)
print(cont_constr.to_dot())
```

The final diagram looks like this:

[image: BDD]

This works well for short sequences, but the last reduction becomes extremely slow when the length gets beyond about 25. I would like something that works for much longer sequences.

I wondered if it would be more efficient in this case to build the BDD directly, since the problem has a lot of structure. However, I can't find any way to directly manipulate BDDs in pyeda.

Does anyone know how I can get this working more efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

This example can be solved for large numbers of variables using the package [`dd`](https://github.com/tulip-control/dd), which can be installed with

```sh
pip install dd
```

For example,

```py
from functools import reduce

from dd.autoref import BDD


def possible_3_grams(farr):
    farr = list(farr)
    poss = [[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
    truths = [[farr[i] if p[i] else ~ farr[i] for i in range(3)] for p in poss]
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, [reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, t) for t in truths])


def main():
    k = 100
    xvars = [f'x{i}' for i in range(k)]
    bdd = BDD()
    bdd.declare(*xvars)
    X = [bdd.add_expr(x) for x in xvars]
    Xc = [X[i-1:i+2] for i in range(1, k-1)]
    cont_constraints = [possible_3_grams(c) for c in Xc]
    cont_constr = reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, cont_constraints)
    print(cont_constr)
    bdd.dump('example.png', [cont_constr])
```

The above uses the pure Python implementation of BDDs in the module `dd.autoref`. There is a Cython implementation available in the module `dd.cudd` that interfaces to the CUDD library in C. This implementation can be used by replacing the import statement

```py
from dd.autoref import BDD
```

with the statement

```py
from dd.cudd import BDD
```

The above script using the class `dd.autoref.BDD` works for `k = 800` (with the `bdd.dump` statement commented). The above script using the class `dd.cudd.BDD` works for `k = 10000`, provided dynamic reordering is first disabled `bdd.configure(reordering=False)`, and constructs a BDD with 39992 nodes (with the `bdd.dump` statement commented).

The diagram for `k = 100` is the following:

[image: diagram of BDD for k=100]

If two-level logic minimization is also of interest, it is implemented in the package [`omega`](https://github.com/tulip-control/omega), an example can be found at: https://github.com/tulip-control/omega/blob/master/examples/minimal_formula_from_bdd.py